Weird problem with non existing USB audio card
I use a little Mele Quieter3Q computer to house a Nextcloud instance, and I have a multiroom audio thing installed (Mopidy, Snapcast) which was running great until an update.
This is running on Ubuntu server 22.04, and was working great until I found that for some reason  an non existing USB audio device on my system.
In alsamixer the normal sound device for the audio 3,5 stereo jack for speakers can´t be found anymore, I only have access to the HDMI outputs (which I don´t use for audio, the HDMI is connected to a TV set though), and I have access to this mystery USB device.
I been at this problem for hours. Tried the suggested solving audio problems in the Ubuntu manual. Tried removing and purging everything to do with alsa, pulseaudio, pipewire, reinstalling them. But still this mystery USB keeps showing in alsamixer.
When I start up the computer I can play a .wav in the "default" device selected in Alsamixer. But audio (stops?) is not working when I try playing music with the Mopidy, Snapcast setup.
Mopidy and Snapcast worked great until this mystery USB device showed up. Still working great on my other device, just not on the server (with Snapclient).
Dmesg shows that there is an USB interface installed:
$ dmesg | grep snd

[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.15.0-118-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ro systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=false snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0 snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver=1

[    0.046715] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.15.0-118-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ro systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=false snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0 snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver=1

[   29.689766] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio

[   29.869486] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: dmic_detect option is deprecated, pass snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver=1 option instead

[   29.869513] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)

[   29.869772] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])

[   30.888787] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: azx_get_response timeout, switching to polling mode: last cmd=0x000f0000

[   31.892850] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: No response from codec, disabling MSI: last cmd=0x000f0000

[   32.900769] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: Codec #0 probe error; disabling it...

[   33.079648] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: Monitor plugged-in, Failed to power up codec ret=[-13]

With inxi -Farz I get this:
    $ inxi -Farz 
    
  Kernel: 5.15.0-118-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.4.0
    parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.15.0-118-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ro
    systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=false snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0
    snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver=1
  Console: pty pts/0 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Mini-pc System: Fanless Mini PC product: Quieter 3 v: N/A serial: <superuser required>
    Chassis: type: 35 serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: Fanless Mini PC model: Rev JSL1 1.10 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: American Megatrends LLC. v: ML_JPL1V1.0 date: 03/15/2022
CPU:
  Info: model: Intel Celeron N5105 bits: 64 type: MCP arch: Tremont family: 6
    model-id: 0x9C (156) stepping: 0 microcode: 0x24000026
  Topology: cpus: 1x cores: 4 smt: <unsupported> cache: L1: 256 KiB
    desc: d-4x32 KiB; i-4x32 KiB L2: 1.5 MiB desc: 1x1.5 MiB L3: 4 MiB desc: 1x4 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 2210 high: 2800 min/max: 800/2900 scaling: driver: intel_pstate
    governor: powersave cores: 1: 2187 2: 2800 3: 1570 4: 2283 bogomips: 15974
  Flags: ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
  Vulnerabilities:
  Type: gather_data_sampling status: Not affected
  Type: itlb_multihit status: Not affected
  Type: l1tf status: Not affected
  Type: mds status: Not affected
  Type: meltdown status: Not affected
  Type: mmio_stale_data mitigation: Clear CPU buffers; SMT disabled
  Type: reg_file_data_sampling mitigation: Clear Register File
  Type: retbleed status: Not affected
  Type: spec_rstack_overflow status: Not affected
  Type: spec_store_bypass mitigation: Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
  Type: spectre_v1 mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
  Type: spectre_v2 mitigation: Enhanced / Automatic IBRS; IBPB: conditional; RSB filling;
    PBRSB-eIBRS: Not affected; BHI: SW loop, KVM: SW loop
  Type: srbds status: Vulnerable: No microcode
  Type: tsx_async_abort status: Not affected
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel JasperLake [UHD Graphics] driver: i915 v: kernel ports: active: HDMI-A-1
    empty: HDMI-A-2 bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:4e61 class-ID: 0300
  Display: server: No display server data found. Headless machine? tty: 172x59
  Monitor-1: HDMI-A-1 model: HKC-TV built: 2018 res: 1366x768 size: 575x323mm (22.6x12.7")
    modes: max: 1366x768 min: 720x400
  Message: GL data unavailable in console. Try -G --display
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel vendor: Realtek driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel
    alternate: snd_sof_pci_intel_icl bus-ID: 00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:4dc8 class-ID: 0403
  Device-2: Anlya.cn ATE1133 type: USB driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid bus-ID: 1-7:4
    chip-ID: 0031:1133 class-ID: 0300 serial: <filter>
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.15.0-118-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: no
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz driver: iwlwifi v: kernel bus-ID: 00:14.3
    chip-ID: 8086:4df0 class-ID: 0280
  IF: wlp0s20f3 state: up mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet driver: r8169 v: kernel
    pcie: gen: 1 speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1 port: 3000 bus-ID: 01:00.0 chip-ID: 10ec:8168
    class-ID: 0200
  IF: enp1s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-1: docker0 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: unknown mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-2: hassio state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: unknown mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-3: veth3b9f957 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-4: veth6699f46 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-5: veth8c19d64 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-6: vethaa56882 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-7: vethd406bdf state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-8: vethe447ea2 state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
  IF-ID-9: vethfa39d4c state: up speed: 10000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Intel AX201 Bluetooth type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8 bus-ID: 1-8:6 chip-ID: 8087:0026
    class-ID: e001
  Report: rfkill ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: down bt-service: not found rfk-block: hardware: no
    software: no address: see --recommends
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.43 TiB used: 510.57 GiB (35.0%)
  SMART Message: Required tool smartctl not installed. Check --recommends
  ID-1: /dev/mmcblk1 maj-min: 179:0 model: A3A444 size: 230.47 GiB block-size: physical: 512 B
    logical: 512 B type: SSD serial: <filter> rev: 0x8 scheme: GPT
  ID-2: /dev/sda maj-min: 8:0 type: USB vendor: Western Digital model: WD Elements 10A2
    size: 931.48 GiB block-size: physical: 512 B logical: 512 B type: N/A serial: <filter>
    rev: 1033 scheme: GPT
  ID-3: /dev/sdb maj-min: 8:16 type: USB model: 1JMicron USB to ATA\x2fATAPI size: 298.09 GiB
    block-size: physical: 512 B logical: 512 B type: N/A serial: <filter> scheme: GPT
Partition:
  ID-1: / raw-size: 928.43 GiB size: 928.43 GiB (100.00%) used: 510.31 GiB (55.0%) fs: btrfs
    dev: /dev/dm-0 maj-min: 253:0 mapped: ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
  ID-2: /boot raw-size: 2 GiB size: 2 GiB (100.00%) used: 258.5 MiB (12.6%) fs: btrfs
    dev: /dev/sda2 maj-min: 8:2
  ID-3: /boot/efi raw-size: 1.05 GiB size: 1.05 GiB (99.80%) used: 6.1 MiB (0.6%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/sda1 maj-min: 8:1
Swap:
  Kernel: swappiness: 60 (default) cache-pressure: 100 (default)
  ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 4 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) priority: -2 file: /swap.img
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 57.0 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Repos:
  Packages: 1955 apt: 1950 lib: 942 snap: 5
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list
    1: deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted
    2: deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted
    3: deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy universe
    4: deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates universe
    5: deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy multiverse
    6: deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates multiverse
    7: deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    8: deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
    9: deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
    10: deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy stable
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mopidy.list
    1: deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/mopidy-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.mopidy.com/ bullseye main contrib non-free
    2: deb-src [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/mopidy-archive-keyring.gpg] https://apt.mopidy.com/ bullseye main contrib non-free
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/redis.list
    1: deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/redis-archive-keyring.gpg] https://packages.redis.io/deb jammy main
Info:
  Processes: 325 Uptime: 1h 34m wakeups: 0 Memory: 7.5 GiB used: 2.08 GiB (27.8%) Init: systemd
  v: 249 runlevel: 5 tool: systemctl Compilers: gcc: 11.4.0 alt: 11 Shell: Bash v: 5.1.16
  running-in: pty pts/0 (SSH) inxi: 3.3.13

It shows the mystery USB device and Pulseaudio seems to be not running. Pulseaudio often refuses to start. Masking and Unmasking doesn´t seem to help.
As you can see inxi -Farz shows the build in INTEL sound device. But if I do:
$ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: ATE1133 [ATE1133], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
    Subdevices: 0/1
    Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

The INTEL device is gone. The intel device is also only showing up as HDMI sinks (which I don´t use) in Alsamixer (I can see those there).
Anybody have any tips for this weird problem. I only see reinstalling the system as the only option left, I would like to avoid that. Everything (nextcloud and Mopidy, Snapcast) was running GREAT!
And NO there was never an USB audio device installed, just 2 external hard drives.

Could be a bad driver is covering up the correct driver.  Might be able to blacklist it.
